# Python, pip not caching

Tags: python, pip

I am rather distressed that pip download cache is not working on my nfs.  And yes nfs does work.

In  my client server

```
/root/.pip/pip.conf
[global]
download-cache=/mnt/nfs/data/nfs
```

I install a pip package and nothing in /mnt/nfs/data/nfs.

This works

```
touch /mnt/nfs/data/nfs/dude.txt
ls /mnt/nfs/data/nfs/
dude.txt
```

Why when I install it doesn't it do what it is supposed to do?

Update:

When I changed the config to the below I get the below message but nothing in dir.  I am not using sudo.  I am as root.

```
[global]
#download-cache=/mnt/nfs/data/nfs
cache-dir=/mnt/nfs/data/nfs


pip install --upgrade pyes
The directory '/mnt/nfs/data/nfs' or its parent directory is not
owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled.
check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing
pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
```

Comment: Have you tried passing `--download-cache /mnt/nfs/data/nfs` during `pip install` and do you have a recent version of `pip` installed?

Comment: yes sudo -H pip2 install --upgrade pip

Comment: pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg

Comment: Are you running `pip` as `root` or `sudo pip` as a regular user? If `sudo` as user: put `.pip/pip.conf` in `$HOME`, instead of `/root/`.

Comment: who owns `/mnt/nfs/data/nfs`?

Comment: chown nobody:nogroup /data/nfs

Comment: well then the solution is in the error message, isn't it? Have you tried `chown root:root dir`?